# Unity 2D: Collision trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision-detection

So here it is, I`am making a game for my thesis. The game is called hacky sack, I`am having a problem when my trigger is true because the collision for my character and the object is passing through and if idon`t have a trigger it was just basically hitting it even when my Player is running.

And can you guys help me on how the Object/Sack going up randomly when it hit. So here is my code :

```
 public void Sipa()
 {
   if (canSipa == true)
    {
     _pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(-400, 1000));
    }
 }
```

}

And here is for my object

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
   {
       _player.GetComponent<PlayerManager>().canSipa = true;
     }
}

 private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
 {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
   {
   _player.GetComponent<PlayerManager>().canSipa = false ;
  }
 }
```

}

Comment: Please post only the *relevant* code. No-one here will scan your entire code-base.

Comment: Ow sorry, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

add a second `collider`, slightly larger then the first, mark it `trigger`. leave the smaller inner `collider` for physics. you "foot" should enter the `trigger` and activiate it, then collide with the inner `collider`. make sure the `collider` marked `trigger` is the larger one.

Comment: Thanks bro, I will try it later. Will come back here if it is succeed.

Comment: Did i do it right? Sorry, I`am just new to unity but have some experienced on coding. https://ibb.co/hQgrF0

Comment: it looks good. functionality is the determiner though, depending on how well it looks timed, you may adjust the trigger collider size up and down. are you getting the behavour you wanted?

Comment: Even though i have no trigger i can kick the object, I just want to when my Player is running it cannot hit the object. And when i kick the object it was just like kissing the collider, it looks no force.

Comment: Yup i can kick it. But no force, Lol

Comment: what input are you using to move? if its a keypress you can set a bool to false, on that button down, and set it to true on that button up. then only kick if its false

Comment: I`am using button and keypress. Is there anyway I can contact you?

Comment: vanethrane@gmail.com

Comment: Hei bro can you give me a example ? this is my code on move `if (move)
        {
            HandleMovement(direction);
            Flip(direction);
        }
        else
        {
            HandleMovement(horizontal);
            Flip(horizontal);
        }
  HandleKicks ();
  ResetValues ();
 }`

Comment: Sorry mavvv just started a new job. Ill give this a look today

Comment: Thanks PrinceOfRavens. I`ll promise if i finish this project i`ll add you on our project Thesis that who help us. Many thanks bro.